# Setting max run time for a SageMaker HyperParameter Tuning job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

My training jobs only run for a minute or two so I have increased the resource limit so I can run a large number (500) in parallel. However, I would like to set some upper bound so I don't accidentally have them run for several hours times 500....

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-limits.html) I can find the following

> Maximum run time for a hyperparameter tuning job: 30 days

30 days is def too much lol but how can I change it? Would love to just be able to set it to stop if it hits a maximum total training time, but unlike the other limits there's no mention that this can changed.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no Tuner parameter that limits the tuner job duration, you could set an effective $ spend limit using the Tuner's [max_jobs](http://%20https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/tuner.html?highlight=tuner#sagemaker.tuner.HyperparameterTuner) parameter:

```
allowed_spend_usd = 50 # 50$
instance_cost_usd_hr = 0.1
total_train_minutes_allowed = allowed_spend_usd * 60 / instance_cost_usd_hr
minutes_per_job = 2 # you know this empirically 
max_jobs = round(total_train_minutes_allowed / minutes_per_job)
###
tuner = HyperparameterTuner(max_jobs=max_jobs, ...)
```

I recommend that you also set a reasonable [max_run](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase) per training job to further ensure that training jobs will finish as fast as you expect (say 300 seconds if you expect 60-120 seconds).